# typo3: mysql database not useable

Tags: mysql, typo3

Currently I try to migrate a typo3 based Webserver to a new machine. (its my first migration, so please don't judge if I did smth wrong).
What I did so far:

- transfer Files via `wget` on new machine
- create dbdump with `mysqldumb`
- transfer dump with `wget`
- create database with `mysql source <dumpfile.sql>`
- create user with access to the db

When I try to connect with the server, typo3 doesn't response. 
And when I try to install typo3 from skretch and replace the new database with the old one, I also run into internal server errors.
Is there a solution on how to migrate the database correctly?

Yours Sincerely,

Sebastian

Comment: Is there any error message involved? Please add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

Mh,

this should not be an issue in general.

We often use following steps:

- [SRC] BackupDatabase: `MYSQL_PWD="DBPASS" mysqldump -uDBUSER --opt -e -Q --skip-comments --single-transaction=true | gzip >dump.sql.gz`
- [SRC] Pack the installation and the used core: `tar -czf transfer.tar.gz ./typo-webfolder ./typo3_src-VERSION`
- Transfer both .gz files to new server (wget, scp, ftp etc )
- [NEW] Deflate files: `tar -xzf transfer.tar.gz`
- [NEW] Create a empty database, using your fav tool
- [NEW] Import database: `gunzip <dump.sql.gz | MYSQL_PWD="DBPASS" mysql -uDBUSER [-hDBHOST] NEWDBNAME`
- [NEW] Adjust DatabaseCredentials in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php'
- [NEW] Recheck symlinks (typo3_src, typo3, index.php)
- [NEW] Recheck .htaccess files - maybe missed to pack and transfer ?
- [NEW] Create FlagFile `touch typo-webfolder/typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL`
- [NEW] Open install tool in Webbrowser ( http://newdomain.tld/typo3/install ), checking requirements, maybe fixing folderstructure and so on, clearing all caches

Eventually clear the typo3temp folder (can be repopulated by the system)

In our projects, we are setting the DB Credentials through AdditionalConfiguration.php based on Enviroment Variables (read from a .env file )

So in generell there should not be any issues, but withour more information it is hard to help you further.

Some things:

- Proxy/TrustedProxy settings
- DomainRecord Settings in the Database ( sys_domain )
- RealUrl Config With DomainName based settings
- .htaccess Canonical rewrite rules based on domain/hostname
- Missing needed php modules etc., wrong php version, checking php error log

Comment: this actually helped a lot, I am now troubling with permission problems (new question). But when I log in to the backend, I cant access with the any user/pw combination I know (old db/new Backend user)

Comment: Also, the original database was about 50GiB, the "new" one is about 5MiB... This doesn't seem right!

Comment: Then there sould be an error on the importing side. Maybe the ssh connection was dropped ? (If youe have done this over ssh):

Try the screen utility to run the so you cann reconnect over ssh and reattach to the import process.

Without any error note it is really hard to came up with a proper solution for your problem.

Comment: So, I run it again over the holiday without errors and it didn't work either. But now I took a look at it via phpMyAdmin and surprisingly the database is empty, only the structrue was built... but in the dump are data involved (checked via `cat` )

Comment: Have you done it using screen ? Have you looked into the mysql error logs ? (if they are enabled ? )

Comment: I didn't receive any errors, evrything was fine. I finally got something to work with: unzip the dump, then import it with the mysql admin user. I had to do it 3 times and the last 3 or 4 tables didn't got the data, but thats OK for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in general your workflow is usable. (don't forget the filesystem `fileadmin/` and `typo3conf/ext/`)
but there are some traps.
be sure to delete the corresponding caches for all changes in filesystem or database.

if you transfer the database: make sure you always use UTF-8 coding of everything!

regarding filesystem: there could be thumbnails or other resized images (folder `__processed__/`) but there also are entries in the database for each file and each resizing.

all extensions or configuration are cached in typo3temp/Code/*, also have in mind the autoloader files.

in most cases you can do a clean-up in the install tool.
so the first thing should be:
**start the install tool, do all checks and remove all temporary information.**